# How to handle Application Update in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I am using VS 2008 with C#

My query is below.
With Clickonce in VS 2008, i am creating a installer. It has an option that "Application should check for updates". Here is the screen shot

[image]

It shows the below Update Information Pop up When you have a new version setup placed in the same location from where the old setup was installed. Below is the screen shot.

[image]

Now, the issue is if you click the skip button and again clicking the shortcut of the installed setup will not show the "Application Update" message and results in manually uninstalling the old setup.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I've never seen the "results in manually installing the old setup" part, the fact that the application update message is not shown is [as per design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2005/06/13/428749.aspx) :

> Clicking on Skip launches the locally installed version of the application AND makes sure you are not prompted for that particular update for a week.

And further more:

> To reitterate, clicking on Skip is equivalent to "Do not prompt me for this particular update for a week". The week time limit is non configurable.
>   Note that you will no be "Prompted" for a week - however clickonce will still check for updates based on you maxAge or beforeApplicationStartup setting. If it detects a newer Update (You skipped V2, however now V3 is available) you will be prompted for the new update.

Comment: Is there any way to prompt the user for the V2 version which is skipped on running the application again ? as already it is not prompting the user in case skip is pressed for the V2 version.

Comment: As per that article, if you never wanted them to skip in the first place, you could set the `minimumRequiredVersion` attribute.

Comment: Can you please explain the below point? I have  release issue to client with version 4.0.10.0 and my current version is 4.0.20.0, to be issued, here what should be the minimum required version so that even after skipping the version 4.0.12.0 update, system again prompts the user for same version on opening the application again ?

Comment: +1 for minimumRequiredVersion. Got to learn something new but the answer was incomplete. Complete answer is minimumRequiredVersion  should be equal to the verion number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have custom behaviour for the application look into the [System.Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.aspx) namespace. You can force updates to download in the background and make the application restart itself so that it's always up to date if that's what you require.

Comment: I want to prompt user again and again after clicking the skip or closing the window,  after opening the application until it is installed..!!

Comment: Do you want the user to accept the update or do you just want the update to be installed? If the latter then you can update the application silently in the background and the next time they run it it will be the newer version

Comment: +1. Thanks for the replies and taking out your precious time.